# Seaborn.distplot with probability rather than probability density function

Tags: seaborn

Can I have seaborn.distplot with y-axis of probability rather than probability density function?

Comment: Do you have a discrete or a continuous distribution? For a continuous distribution you need to specify explicit bins (preferably equal width) and multiply the y-axis by that width to get the probability of each bin.  [wikipedia explaining that a pdf is very different from a probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) For a discrete distribution you could just count each value and divide by the number of samples (a `distplot` is only meant for continuous distributions).  Do you have some sample data and indications of what you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that this is what you meant, but:

```
ax = sns.distplot(x, rug=True, rug_kws={"color": "g"},
              kde_kws={"color": "k", "lw": 3, "label": "KDE"},
              hist_kws={"histtype": "step", "linewidth": 3,
                        "alpha": 1, "color": "g"})
```

Seems like a [rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html#seaborn.rugplot) could be a solution to your problem as well.

Taken from the seaborn documentation:

1. rugplot:
   Draw small vertical lines to show each observation in a distribution.